# LM2596 random shutdown

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Update:
I swapped out the LM2596 with the TI version from Digikey and so far so good.  My first batch of LM2596 chips are from China (unknown brand). Anyone else ran into issues with China versions of LM2596?

I'm using a LM2596S-12 to regulate 36v DC input to 12v with custom PCB.  I've made 12 boards and all seems to work initial.  Out of the 12 boards, 3 of them have random shutdown.  During shutdown, the output of the LM2596S-12 have 0v and the 36v DC input is still on.  I can't get the LM2596S-12 to function again until power reset (remove input voltage then re-apply input voltage).  At times, the shutdown occur after running for couple hours, and other time it would run fine for over a week before shutdown.  I check to temperature and LM2596S-12 stays cool to touch when working.  The typical load for output of LM2596S-12 is about 200mA to 400mA.  I've even added a small heatsink on the LM2596S-12 but random shutdown still occurs.

I'm using typical ref design for fixed output voltage for LM2596.
[image: Ref]

For my circuit, I tied the pin 5 (on/off) to ground for continuous on.  Cin is not shown the below schematic crop.
[image: SCH]

My layout
[image: LAY]

Comment: What kind of diode is D12? My gut feeling is that it is just a straight layout issue. Your traces are long and thin, which are not exactly suitable for switching supply circuits. Carefully read Section 11 of the datasheet and do as much as possible to copy their design unless you understand where and how you can deviate from it.

Comment: Where is the input (pin 1) decoupling capacitor? It should be right beside pins 1 and 3.

Comment: D12 diode is NRVTS245ESFT1GOSCT-ND (DIODE SCHOTTKY 45V 2A SOD123FL), http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&itemSeq=187858794&uq=635887043164770670

Comment: Input decoupling caps are labeled C1 and C2 in the Layout.

Comment: @pgvoorhees, I understand the traces may not be ideal.  Would trace issue causes random shutdown that need power reset?  My thinking is that thin trace would just cause the feedback loop not keep up with the output voltage??

Comment: @dlcircuits In short, in any circuit with switched currents: yes. Layout issues can cause all kinds of things. Excessive heating, premature failure, inability to perform the desired task are all reasonable outcomes when there is a poor layout. 

Please don't misunderstand I'm not judging you, but DCDC layout is tough because all the little imperfections in the actual physical limitations in the PCB (the fact that copper isn't a perfect conductor, the stray inductances and capacitances, etc.) are not ignorable any more.

Comment: @dlcircuits I posted an evernote with primer material I read for when I designed my first DC-DC converter. The "layout issues.ppt" is particularly helpful for a gut-check layout appraisal. 

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/def372fc-82e7-45dd-9a4c-a6a7c3986c0b/34fbe5de8b9d3d66

At the end: I would just reiterate to try the recommended layout first. If you need to deviate, you'll have to spend a lot of time thinking it over.

Comment: I seem to also have the same problem with an [eBay LM2596 5v output module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/114531603369). It locks up after a few hours. [Edited by a moderator.]

Answer (score 1):

If you're not getting hot, pin 5 might be your problem. I agree with @pgvoorhees that the layout is not ideal.  Pin 5 is directly in the current path so that at switch time it sees the current transient which can make it a different voltage from pin 3 due to the inductance of the current path.  I would try cutting the trace to pin 5 and jumpering from the diode to pin 3 and from pin 5 to pin 3 so the connection from pin 5 to pin 3 has no current.  This will keep pin 5 at the same voltage as pin 3. (too long for a comment)

Comment: If it's pin 5 that's turning it off, wouldn't once the inductance current goes away, shouldn't it turn back on?

Comment: I should have made it clear that I am suspecting a latch-up here, due to the voltage on pin 5 going below ground and/or above its maximum.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch-up

Comment: I've tested a few with pin 5 left open as LM2596 is set to ON with pin 5 ground or open.  I still get random shutdowns.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same rare issue with the [module version of LM2596S  from ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/10pcs-Mini-Power-Supply-Step-Down-Module-LM2596S-3A-DC-to-DC-Buck-Converter-New/263929616552?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) with 32V IN and 5V OUT.
Without bleeding resistor at the output it took more than 3 minutes out of power to reset back to working condition. I suspect transient at input because my failing 2 cases was when the same input was loaded with a dc motor that some had mechanical issues (probably some more spikes there from brushes). i added some bleeding resistors on output on my old design and some input transient protection. In my newer design i am using xl4015 instead, no issues yet but am not using it long enough time to be sure.